# Why isn't my function defined?

Tags: javascript

How come this returns an error? 
In my head tag...

```
var movieArray = [
["Everything is Illuminated", "0", ""],
["The Girl Who Leapt Through Time (Toki wo kakeru shojo)", "1", "<ol><li><span class=\"bold quote_actor\">Kosuke Yoshiyama: </span><span class=\"line\">It&#039;s not that rare. Many girls do it at your age.</span></li>                                                </ol>"],
["Freedom Writers", "0", ""],
["Inside Man", "0", ""]
];

function checkAnswer(this.value) {
    if (this.value == 0) {
        alert ("Wrong answer!");
    } else {
        alert ("Correct Answer!");
    }

}
```

In the body...

```
<p><a id="0" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="0" onclick="checkAnswer(this.value)">Everything is Illuminated</a></p>
<p><a id="1" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="1" onclick="checkAnswer(this.value)">The Girl Who Leapt Through Time (Toki wo kakeru shojo)</a></p>
```

The error is checkAnswer() is not defined. How come?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get more errors? `function checkAnswer(this.value)` is not valid JavaScript, it needs to be `function checkAnswer(value)`

Comment: where can you see that error?

Comment: You do know that you've got unescaped double-quotes in your second movie, right?  And that will make everything crash and burn all the way down, if it's all defined in the global scope...

Comment: If i change it to function checkAnswer(value) and then if (value == 0) {, I still get ReferenceError: checkAnswer is not defined.
The error is in FF's error console window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to escape `"` inside array elements by adding backslash

```
var movieArray = [
    ["Everything is Illuminated", "0", ""],
    ["The Girl Who Leapt Through Time (Toki wo kakeru shojo)", "1", "<ol><li><span class=\"bold quote_actor\">Kosuke Yoshiyama: </span><span class=\"line\">It&#039;s not that rare. Many girls do it at your age.</span></li>                                                </ol>"],
    ["Freedom Writers", "0", ""],
    ["Inside Man", "0", ""]
    ];

function checkAnswer(arg1) {
    if (arg1 == 0) {
        alert("Wrong answer!");
    } else {
        alert("Correct Answer!");
    }

}​
```

Secondly `this.value` should be passed while calling the checkAnswer() and not at the time of defitinion

Comment: How does your answer have data the user never specified in the question?

Comment: @Cthulhu the OP removed that data, it was originally there.

Comment: You might also mention that `this.value` is not a correct function argument

Comment: Yep, it was this (*facepalm*). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How did everyone miss the `this.value` in the arguments list? It should be an identifier, such as `myvalue`. This is the reason why `checkAnswer` is not defined.

Now, as for the rest of the code, you can't use `this` in the `checkAnswer` function as it will refer to the global object, not the link. Also, links don't support the `value` property, so you need to use `getAttribute` or just put the value in the `onClick` event outright.

```
function checkAnswer(myval) {
    if (myval == 0) {
        alert ("Wrong answer!");
    } else {
        alert ("Correct Answer!");
    }
}

<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onclick="checkAnswer(0)">Everything is Illuminated</a></p>
<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onclick="checkAnswer(1)">The Girl Who Leapt Through Time (Toki wo kakeru shojo)</a></p>
```

I also removed the `id` attributes, since an ID starting with a number is not valid except in HTML5 (and even then they're not a good idea due to older browsers still in widespread use, and even without that they're meaningless)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I didn't realise about the things you mentioned, but I've learned a lot because of it.

Answer (score 0):

Error in your function syntax .

Error :

```
function checkAnswer(this.value) {
```

A function syntax must be a `functionName(formalParameterName)` . You are passing a value in a object in a function parameter this will lead into error . You have to change this to `function checkAnswer(param)` .